# I can not restore the title ActionBar at repairing the fragment of backstack

Tags: android

opens when the first fragment, I put in the header in ActionBar

```
 getActivity().setTitle("Guests" + hotel + "" + "(" + count + ")");
```

if the opening of this piece another, I put a new header and fragment is placed in the backstack and hide

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        FragmentTransaction fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment guestFragment = new Guest();
        fTrans.hide(this);
        fTrans.add(R.id.content_frame, guestFragment, "guest");
        fTrans.addToBackStack(null);
        fTrans.commit();
    }
```

In new Fragment correctly exhibit title

```
getActivity().setTitle(guests.get(0).getName());
```

but when I click the back button and opens the old fragment header remains the same. I do not know which method is triggered when the fragment pulls out from backstack.

I tried onResume, onStart but nothing happens

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        getActivity().setTitle("fgfdhgfdjhj");
        super.onResume();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your `setTitle` method to `onActivityCreated()`.

Comment: I use the fTrans.addToBackStack(null); 
onActivityCreated not called

Answer (score 0):

in first fragment `public static String header;` and `header = "Guests" + hotel + "" + "(" + count + ")";`

in second fragment

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        getActivity().setTitle(GuestsList.header);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

I do not know how it is right but it works. if someone knows a better solution please write